# Using I2C on a dsPIC33E

Tags: pic, i2c

I'm having a problem using I2C on a dsPIC33EP512MU810 . I use the peripheral library for PIC24 and dsPIC33 in order to manage the registers but also wrote some functions myself. Here are the functions I use for I2C

```
#include <xc.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include "I2C1.h"
#include <i2c.h> 
#include <libpic30.h> 
#include "common.h"

void Open_I2C1(void)
{
    // Configre SCA/SDA pin as open-drain. This may change from device to device.
    //Refer the datasheet for more information.
    ODCDbits.ODCD9 = 0;
    ODCDbits.ODCD10 = 0;
    OpenI2C1((I2C2_ON & I2C2_IDLE_CON & I2C2_CLK_HLD & I2C2_IPMI_DIS &
             I2C2_7BIT_ADD & I2C2_SLW_EN & I2C2_SM_DIS &
             I2C2_GCALL_DIS & I2C2_STR_DIS &
             I2C2_NACK & I2C2_ACK_DIS & I2C2_RCV_DIS &
             I2C2_STOP_DIS & I2C2_RESTART_DIS &
             I2C2_START_DIS), 0x4E);

    IdleI2C1();

    I2C1CONbits.I2CEN = 1;
    IEC1bits.MI2C1IE = 1;
    IFS1bits.MI2C1IF = 0;

}

void WriteByte_I2C1(unsigned char WriteAddressIC, unsigned char WriteAddressRegister, uint8_t MSByte, uint8_t LSByte)
{
    ResetVariables_I2C1();

    Start_I2C1();
    while(!IFS1bits.MI2C1IF);
    IFS1bits.MI2C1IF=0;

    //Write Slave address and set master for transmission
    MasterWriteI2C1(WriteAddressIC);
    WaitFlag_I2C1();
    WaitForACK_I2C1();  

    MasterWriteI2C1(WriteAddressRegister);
    WaitFlag_I2C1();
    WaitForACK_I2C1();

    MasterWriteI2C1(MSByte);  
    WaitFlag_I2C1();   
    WaitForACK_I2C1();

    MasterWriteI2C1(LSByte);  
    WaitFlag_I2C1();   
    WaitForACK_I2C1();

    ResetVariables_I2C1();  
    StopI2C1();   
    WaitFlag_I2C1();  
    WaitForACK_I2C1();   
    IdleI2C1();

}

uint16_t ReadByte_I2C1 (unsigned char ReadAddressIC, unsigned char RegisterAddress)
{
    uint8_t Byte = 0x00;
    uint16_t result = 0x0000;
    ResetVariables_I2C1();
    Start_I2C1();
    while((!IFS1bits.MI2C1IF)) {

    }

    //Write Slave address and set master for transmission
    MasterWriteI2C1(ReadAddressIC);      
    WaitFlag_I2C1();
    WaitForACK_I2C1();

    MasterWriteI2C1(RegisterAddress);
    WaitFlag_I2C1();
    WaitForACK_I2C1();

    ResetVariables_I2C1();
    RestartI2C1();
    WaitFlag_I2C1();

    MasterWriteI2C1(ReadAddressIC + 1);
    WaitFlag_I2C1();
    WaitForACK_I2C1();
    ResetVariables_I2C1();


    I2C1CONbits.RCEN = 1;
    while(I2C1CONbits.RCEN)
    {
        LATCbits.LATC2 ^= 1;
    }
    I2C1STATbits.I2COV = 0;
    Byte = I2C1RCV;
    result = Byte<<8;
    WaitFlag_I2C1();


    I2C1CONbits.RCEN = 1;
    while(I2C1CONbits.RCEN)
    {
        LATCbits.LATC2 ^= 1;
    }
    I2C1STATbits.I2COV = 0;
    Byte = I2C1RCV;
    result |= Byte;
    WaitFlag_I2C1();

    ResetVariables_I2C1();
    NotAckI2C1();
    WaitFlag_I2C1();
    ResetVariables_I2C1();
    StopI2C1();
    WaitFlag_I2C1();
    IdleI2C1();

    return Byte;

}

void ResetVariables_I2C1(void)
{
    I2C1CONbits.ACKEN=0;
    I2C1CONbits.PEN=0;
    I2C1CONbits.RCEN=0;
    I2C1CONbits.RSEN=0;
    I2C1CONbits.SEN=0;
}

void WaitFlag_I2C1(void)
{
    while(!IFS1bits.MI2C1IF);
    LATCbits.LATC2 ^=1;  // wait for flag to be high
    IFS1bits.MI2C1IF=0;
}
void WaitForACK_I2C1(void)
{
    while(I2C1STATbits.ACKSTAT); // wait for ack receive from slave
    LATCbits.LATC2 ^=1; 
}
void Start_I2C1(void){
    I2C1CONbits.SEN = 1; 
}
```

When I use the Write-function, the function stops right after sending the start condidtion because the flag never gets set. I measured it by the good old LED step technique where I light a LED after each step in order to see when it stops. Also I took a look at the SDA and SCL Line with an osciloscope and I can only see start conditions. 
I also checked my hardware setup, e.g. is everything connected, no short circuits or almost short circuits and checked if I can use other devices to communicate to the IC I want to talk to with the dsPIC33.
I also checked if I use the right pins. I use the ASD1/RD9 and ASCL1/RD10, which means that I have to set 'ALTI2C1 = ON' in the configuration bits.

But now I ran out of ideas what it could possibly be that I do wrong here and why the flag is not getting up. I would be thankfull if someone could point me in the right direction here

Comment: General advice for the EP series - check the errata. There are some significant oopsies with the I2C peripheral on the EP series that need workarounds in firmware. The EP silicon changed a lot from the FJ series...

Answer (score 1):

I think I found the answer. In the initialisation function I switched the I2C-Interrupt on, although I dont have an ISR. Not setting IEC1bits.MI2C1IE solved my problem